# Is it possible that my reputation has been frozen?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, community-wiki

I am just wondering because I received a couple of upvotes and marked a question as answered on Cross Validated and my rep didn't go up. I have no idea why it might have been frozen so I was just wondering. [the upvotes were [on Cross Validated today]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/how-far-will-self-study-get-me)

Comment: You probably hit the rep cap.  You can only gain 200 rep from upvotes per day; accepted answers don't count, though.

Comment: @AdamRackis He didn't, but I also don't see a problem if we're talking about the 4th; he got two question upvotes and accepted something and got +12 for it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No I'm taking about today.

Comment: @Bart The upvotes are still there but it seems my question became a CW.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Yeah, removed my comment. I thought you were referring to another account. CW is the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [post you linked to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47576) is a Community Wiki post and upvotes (or downvotes) don't count on them.

[The moderator converted it to CW](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/47576/revisions). Only moderators can convert Questions to CW, while users can convert answers to CW by themselves by ticking the checkbox at the bottom-right of the answer field:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. How did it become community wiki?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid [The moderator converted it to CW](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/47576/revisions). :) By the way: only moderators can convert Questions to CW (while users can convert answers to CW by themselves).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that I missed it.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Glad to be of service!